# VBA Getting Run time error '438'object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying to get data from className. I am getting the error

> Run time error '438'object doesn't support this property or method

but i am successfully able to get data from ID.  Please help.

Below is my code which I have tried.

```
Sub Use_Cell_text()
    Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
    driver.Get "https://www.99acres.com/2-bhk-bedroom-apartment-flat-for-sale-in-jaypee-greens-kosmos-sector-134-noida-942-sq-ft-r1-spid-E31025131?pos=SEARCH&sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzIjICB8IG5vaWRhIzQjIHwgQ1AxIHwgWSB8IzE3IyAgfCAxICMyI3wgIHwgMzIzNzA4ODksMzEwMjUxMzEgfCAxIHwgNyM2IyB8IDEgfCM0MCMgIHw=&fsl=Y"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Range("B1") = driver.FindElementById("headerDescription").Text
        dd = driver.FindElementById("pdPrice").Text
        dd1 = driver.FindElementById("pricePerUnitArea").Text
        Range("B2") = dd & dd1
        dd3 = driver.findElementByClassName("pdPropAddress").Text
        Range("B3") = dd3
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: Hi braX i am getting error at dd3 = driver.findElementByClassName("pdPropAddress").Text

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but until someone else comes along to answer, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189182/how-does-this-simple-java-selenium-webdriver-code-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will fetch you the result you are after.

```
Sub Use_Cell_text()
    Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver, post As Object

    driver.get "https://www.99acres.com/2-bhk-bedroom-apartment-flat-for-sale-in-jaypee-greens-kosmos-sector-134-noida-942-sq-ft-r1-spid-E31025131?pos=SEARCH&sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzIjICB8IG5vaWRhIzQjIHwgQ1AxIHwgWSB8IzE3IyAgfCAxICMyI3wgIHwgMzIzNzA4ODksMzEwMjUxMzEgfCAxIHwgNyM2IyB8IDEgfCM0MCMgIHw=&fsl=Y"

    For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("pdPropAddress")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi All thanks for the reply!!! , @Mithu your code is working fine thanks for your wonderful help!!!!

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to mark this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not type in capitals in reserved words when you enter program lines.

Type in

```
dd1 = driver.findelementbyid("pricePerUnitArea").text
```

and the VBA editor will change it to

```
dd1 = driver.FindElementById("pricePerUnitArea").Text
```

(capitals in FindElementById)

Type in

```
dd3 = driver.findelementbyclassname("pdPropAddress").text
```

and the vba editor will not change it, which means that it does not recognize the

```
findelementbyclassname
```

Your line should be

```
dd3 = driver.FindElementByClass("pdPropAddress").Text
```

The `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` line is useless unless you put a dot in front of the range objects, `.Range("B1") ...`

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B1") = driver.FindElementById("headerDescription").Text
End With
```

is the same as

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = driver.FindElementById("headerDescription").Text
```

Comment: This works for me. Excel 2301 (Build 16026.20146) Click to Run Current Channel, Edge 110.0.1587.50 *do not type in capitals in reserved words when you enter program line*